# recovery data from stand alone docker container after accidentally deleted my vm on azure

Tags: linux, restore, docker, azure, ubuntu-16.04

I deleted my vm on azure but the disk still  exist in resource group I mounted 
a new machine and attach the disk[vhd] into it

I mounted the disk in /datadrive and I can see my docker container

can I make `sudo docker start 74249224a191be10cf7f65609a373879a159c19d84d50656408dcd5ffdf2cb17`
to get the generated data back no volume is attached on this container
I tried installing docker and copying  the container from `/datadrive/var/lib/docker/containers/` to its equivalent in the new machine but even after I copy the files I can't start the container with error

```
Error response from daemon: No such container: 74249224a191be10cf7f65609a373879a159c19d84d50656408dcd5ffdf2cb17
```

Error: failed to start containers: 74249224a191be10cf7f65609a373879a159c19d84d50656408dcd5ffdf2cb17

Comment: You could not,  why create a new VM by using your VHD?

Comment: so I can access the disk once again azure store the disks in vhd formate inside the container is a simple CMS system so I was trying to get the latest data from it

Comment: Based on my knowledge, if you recreate the VM by using your VHD, it don't lose your data.

Comment: yes but the container wasn't connected to a volume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to you description, I suggest you had better recreate your VM by using your VHD. Based on my experience, docker depends on some system configuration not only `/var/lib/docker/containers/`. In your new VM, if you could not configure them correctly, you could not start your docker.

It is easy to recreate your VM by using this [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-specialized-vhd-existing-vnet).

After you recreate your VM, you could migrate docker container to another VM. This is a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734086/how-to-move-docker-containers-between-different-hosts) about this.

Comment: you are awesome this template saved my day thanks :D